# What are the Yaaxil and how did they come to be?

Tags: lara-croft-tomb-raider

In the latest Tomb Raider game, *Shadow of the Tomb Raider*, there is a race of beings called the Yaaxil. They are humanoid in form but not exactly human.

[image: Several Yaaxil]

Is it ever explained what exactly they are and how they came to be?

Comment: https://tombraider.fandom.com/wiki/Yaaxil

Comment: @Valorum Unfortunately, the wikia just details the events of the game and gives no history on them.

Answer (score 4):

Well, they were made for the purpose of being Paititi guards. But they guard the box of Ix Chel. I was very confused on that matter because I am Mayan and so is Ix Chel. But Peru and Paititi are Inca. There is some crossover but I'm not exactly sure why the Inca are protecting the Maya because it is based on the Maya apocalypse. They are supernatural so there will not be an explanation of how they came to be. Like the other Maya gods and goddesses. They only had a purpose and were worshipped.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer in this comment thread, the Yaaxil are indeed Mayan but I myself also had a hard time understanding if Paititi is Mayan or Inca - you would think Inca because of the location in Peru but in the opening of the game it is mentioned that the Mayans did indeed come to Peru in order to hide their box. The city itself doesn't clear this however, since texts from the Mayans, Incans and even the Aztecs can be found so it is a bit of a stretch.

Regardless of their culture however, it is explained that the Yaaxil were created in the heavens by the gods who also created both the Silver Box and the dagger-key from Ix Chel and Chak Chel respectively in order to add as guards to the silver box. After the box was taken they lost their purpose but they still guard Paititi since their leader, a priestess known as the Crimson Fire, must take the place of Chak Chel next to the chosen one as Ix Chel when the box is to be unlocked in order to renew to the sun. Once this has happened, they are supposed to return to the heavens from where they came. That is the most accurate explanation the game gives about their origin.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where is it explained?  Could you add any quotes or citations to your answer?

Comment: Can you give some more details. Which game? Who says it? What, precisely did they say about it? Is there any reason why we should believe them?